# Selection with .loc in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython, selection

I saw this code in someone's iPython notebook, and I'm very confused as to how this code works. As far as I understood, pd.loc[] is used as a location based indexer where the format is:

```
df.loc[index,column_name]
```

However, in this case, the first index seems to be a series of boolean values. Could someone please explain to me how this selection works. I tried to read through the documentation but I couldn't figure out an explanation. Thanks!

```
iris_data.loc[iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor', 'class'] = 'Iris-versicolor'
```

[image]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.loc` can take one or two indexers.  For the rest of the post, I'll represent the first indexer as `i` and the second indexer as `j`.

If only one indexer is provided, it applies to the index of the dataframe and the missing indexer is assumed to represent all columns.  So the following two examples are equivalent.

1. `df.loc[i]`
2. `df.loc[i, :]`

Where `:` is used to represent all columns.

If both indexers are present, `i` references index values and `j` references column values.

---

Now we can focus on what types of values `i` and `j` can assume.  Let's use the following dataframe `df` as our example:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=['A', 'B'], columns=['X', 'Y'])
```

`loc` has been written such that `i` and `j` can be

1. **scalars** that should be values in the respective index objects

   ```
   df.loc['A', 'Y']

   2
   ```
2. **arrays** whose elements are also members of the respective index object (notice that the order of the array I pass to `loc` is respected

   ```
   df.loc[['B', 'A'], 'X']

   B    3
   A    1
   Name: X, dtype: int64
   ```

   - Notice the dimensionality of the return object when passing arrays.  `i` is an array as it was above, `loc` returns an object in which an index with those values is returned.  In this case, because `j` was a scalar, `loc` returned a `pd.Series` object.  We could've manipulated this to return a dataframe if we passed an array for `i` and `j`, and the array could've have just been a single value'd array.

     ```
     df.loc[['B', 'A'], ['X']]

        X
     B  3
     A  1
     ```
3. **boolean arrays** whose elements are `True` or `False` and whose length matches the length of the respective index.  In this case, `loc` simply grabs the rows (or columns) in which the boolean array is `True`.

   ```
   df.loc[[True, False], ['X']]

      X
   A  1
   ```

---

In addition to what indexers you can pass to `loc`, it also enables you to make assignments.  Now we can break down the line of code you provided.

```
iris_data.loc[iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor', 'class'] = 'Iris-versicolor'
```

1. `iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor'` returns a boolean array.
2. `class` is a scalar that represents a value in the columns object.
3. `iris_data.loc[iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor', 'class']` returns a `pd.Series` object consisting of the `'class'` column for all rows where `'class'` is `'versicolor'`
4. When used with an assignment operator:

   ```
   iris_data.loc[iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor', 'class'] = 'Iris-versicolor'
   ```

   We assign `'Iris-versicolor'` for all elements in column `'class'` where `'class'` was `'versicolor'`

Answer (score 7):

This is using dataframes from the `pandas` package. The "index" part can be either a single index, a list of indices, or a list of booleans. This can be read about in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

So the `index` part specifies a subset of the rows to pull out, and the (optional) `column_name` specifies the column you want to work with from that subset of the dataframe. So if you want to update the 'class' column but only in rows where the class is currently set as 'versicolor', you might do something like what you list in the question:

```
iris_data.loc[iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor', 'class'] = 'Iris-versicolor'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a pandas data-frame and it's using label base selection tool with `df.loc` and in it, there are two inputs, one for the row and the other one for the column, so in the row input it's selecting all those row values where the value saved in the column `class` is `versicolor`, and in the column input it's selecting the column with label `class`, and assigning `Iris-versicolor` value to them.
So basically it's replacing all the cells of column `class` with value `versicolor` with `Iris-versicolor`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Whenever [slicing](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-slice-a-dataframe-in-pandas/) (`a:n`) can be used, it can be replaced by [fancy indexing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html) (e.g. `[a,b,c,...,n]`). Fancy indexing is nothing more than listing explicitly all the index values instead of specifying only the limits.
2. Whenever fancy indexing can be used, it can be replaced by a list of Boolean values (a [mask](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html)) the same size than the index. The value will be `True` for index values that would have been included in the fancy index, and `False` for the values that would have been excluded. It's another way of listing some index values, but which can be easily automated in NumPy and Pandas, e.g by a logical comparison (like in your case).

The second replacement possibility is the one used in your example. In:

```
iris_data.loc[iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor', 'class'] = 'Iris-versicolor'
```

the mask

```
iris_data['class'] == 'versicolor'
```

is a replacement for a long and silly fancy index which would be list of row numbers where `class` column (a Series) has the value `versicolor`.

Whether a Boolean mask appears within a `.iloc` or `.loc` (e.g. `df.loc[mask]`) indexer or directly as the index (e.g. `df[mask]`) depends on wether a slice is allowed as a direct index. Such cases are shown in the following indexer cheat-sheet:

[image: Pandas indexers loc and iloc cheat-sheet]
<sup>Pandas indexers loc and iloc cheat-sheet</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's `pandas` label-based selection, as explained here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label

The boolean array is basically a selection method using a mask.