# Python .loc confusion

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, kaggle

I am doing a Kaggle tutorial for Titanic using the Datacamp platform.

I understand the use of .loc within Pandas - to select values by row using column labels...

My confusion comes from the fact that in the Datacamp tutorial, we want to locate all the "Male" inputs within the "Sex" column, and replace it with the value of 0. They use the following piece of code to do it:

```
titanic.loc[titanic["Sex"] == "male", "Sex"] = 0
```

Can someone please explain how this works? I thought .loc took inputs of row and column, so what is the == for?

Shouldn't it be:

```
titanic.loc["male", "Sex"] = 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: [**This answer might be helpful**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891687/2336654)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It set column `Sex` to `1` if condition is `True` only, another values are untouched:

```
titanic["Sex"] == "male"
```

Sample:

```
titanic = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male','female', 'male']})
print (titanic)
      Sex
0    male
1  female
2    male

print (titanic["Sex"] == "male")
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Sex, dtype: bool

titanic.loc[titanic["Sex"] == "male", "Sex"] = 0
print (titanic)

0       0
1  female
2       0
```

It is very similar by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) - it select only values of column `Sex` by condition:

```
print (titanic.loc[titanic["Sex"] == "male", "Sex"])
0    male
2    male
Name: Sex, dtype: object
```

But I think here better is use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) if only `male` and `female` values need convert to some another values:

```
titanic = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male','female', 'male']})
titanic["Sex"] = titanic["Sex"].map({'male':0, 'female':1})
print (titanic)
   Sex
0    0
1    1
2    0
```

EDIT:

Primary [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is used for set new value by index and columns:

```
titanic = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male','female', 'male']}, index=['a','b','c'])
print (titanic)
      Sex
a    male
b  female
c    male

titanic.loc["a", "Sex"] = 0
print (titanic)
      Sex
a       0
b  female
c    male

titanic.loc[["a", "b"], "Sex"] = 0
print (titanic)
    Sex
a     0
b     0
c  male
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!