# Pandas select rows and columns based on boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe with about 50 columns and >100 rows. I want to select columns `'col_x'`, `'col_y'` where `'col_z' < m`. Is there a simple way to do this, similar to `df[df['col3'] < m]` and `df[['colx','coly']]` but combined?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's break down your problem. You want to

1. Filter rows based on some boolean condition
2. You want to select a subset of columns from the result.

For the first point, the condition you'd need is -

```
df["col_z"] < m
```

For the second requirement, you'd want to specify the list of columns that you need -

```
["col_x", "col_y"]
```

How would you combine these two to produce an expected output with pandas? The most straightforward way is using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) -

```
df.loc[df["col_z"] < m, ["col_x", "col_y"]]
```

The first argument selects rows, and the second argument selects columns.

---

**More About `loc`**

Think of this in terms of the relational algebra operations - *selection* and *projection*. If you're from the SQL world, this would be a relatable equivalent. The above operation, in SQL syntax, would look like this -

```
SELECT col_x, col_y     # projection on columns
FROM df
WHERE col_z < m         # selection on rows
```

`pandas` loc allows you to specify index labels for selecting rows. For example, if you have a dataframe -

```
   col_x  col_y
a      1      4
b      2      5
c      3      6
```

To select index `a`, and `c`, and `col_x` you'd use -

```
df.loc[['a', 'c'], ['col_x']]

   col_x
a      1
c      3
```

Alternatively, for selecting by a boolean condition (using a series/array of `bool` values, as your original question asks), where all values in `col_x` are odd -

```
df.loc[(df.col_x % 2).ne(0), ['col_y']]

   col_y
a      4
c      6
```

For details, `df.col_x % 2` computes the modulus of each value with respect to `2`. The `ne(0)` will then compare the value to `0`, and return `True` if it isn't (all odd numbers are selected like this). Here's what that expression results in -

```
(df.col_x % 2).ne(0)

a     True
b    False
c     True
Name: col_x, dtype: bool
```

---

**Further Reading**

- [10 Minutes to Pandas - Selection by Label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#selection-by-label)
- [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

  - [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- [Selection with .loc in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890713/selection-with-loc-in-python)
- [pandas loc vs. iloc vs. ix vs. at vs. iat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat)