# How to read data from a file with a nonstandard separator and plot the values

Tags: python, regex, matplotlib, plot

I've got a .txt file containing numbers like the following:

No. ---  Amount --------  Location

1 -----  23.5   --------  -0.0039

3 -----  2.093  --------   0.992

7 -----  1.211  --------   0.3929

5 -----  0.898  --------  -1.8933

and so on

I've got approx. 700 numbers. Now I want to plot and visualize those numbers. To be exact: I want to show the "Amount" on the x-Axis and the "Location" on the y-Axis. The graph should resemble a sine curve.
Moreover, I want to choose certain numbers. For example, only No. 1 and No. 2. That means, I need to read in the Amount and the Location of Number 1 and Number 2.

I have never worked before with Python or with Matplotlib. Since I hope that somebody could help me out or give me some hints.

So far, I've got the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io

numbers_file = open('numbers_file.txt').read().replace(',',' ')
numbers_data = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(numbers_file),skiprows=1)

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
y = np.sin(x)
beta = x

plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
plt.title('Companies amount and location')
plt.plot(x,y, label=r'sin( $\beta$ )')

plt.xlabel(r'$\beta$')
plt.ylabel('Location')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Beyond that, I want to use a specific textfile entry as a Start Point and as an End Point for my data graph. Some entries (access via 'No.' in the text file) should be visualized as maximum and as a minimum.

I would be very thankful for every help I can get because I am kinda lost on how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

- The easiest way to load the file, considering the unconventional separator, is to create a [`pandas.DataFrmae`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which can have a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for the separator.

  - Don't specify `sep` and `engine` if the separator is a `,`
- The data can then be plotted with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.
- There are many ways to select values based on another column, which are covered by other answers.

  - [extract column value based on another column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36684013/7758804)
  - [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/7758804)
  - [Pandas select rows and columns based on boolean condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48035493/7758804)

    - `selected = df[df['No.'].isin([1, 7])]`
- **Tested in `python 3.9.7`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the data in from the file
df = pd.read_csv('numbers_file.txt', sep=' -* ', engine='python')

# display(df)
   No.  Amount  Location
0    1  23.500   -0.0039
1    3   2.093    0.9920
2    7   1.211    0.3929
3    5   0.898   -1.8933

# plot
ax = df.plot(x='Amount', y='Location')
```

[image]

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Amount', y='Location')
```

[image]