# pandas cumsum skip column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I am new to pandas and I can add to cumsum as

`df.cumsum(axis=1)`

```
   y0  y1  y2
0   2   3   4
1   2   2   3
2   0   0   0
3   1   2   3
   y0  y1  y2
0   2   5   9
1   2   4   7
2   0   0   0
3   1   3   6
```

But is there way to perform on only first 2 columns i.e. skip y2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to exclude `y2`, find `cumsum` and concat `y2` back.

```
pd.concat([df[['y0', 'y1']].cumsum(axis=1),df['y2']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    y0  y1  y2
0   2   5   4
1   2   4   3
2   0   0   0
3   1   3   3
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `.loc` to select only the columns you care about.

```
cols = ['y0', 'y1']
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].cumsum(axis=1)
```

Output

```
   y0  y1  y2
0   2   5   4
1   2   4   3
2   0   0   0
3   1   3   3
```

---

`loc` is a flexible way to slice a DataFrame and in general follows the format:

`.loc[row_labels, column_labels]`

where an `:` can be used to indicate all rows, or all_columns.

Comment: Thanks:) Could you add a quick explanation of what that loc function actually does? With the `:` and everything

Comment: @Greedo I added some information, but there's a better lengthy description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890713/selection-with-loc-in-python