# How to understand a function which splits the data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, training-data, k-fold

Can someone help me understanding what this function does?

I understand up to the line print but after that I'm a bit lost. Starting from `train_data`.

```
def stratifiedShuffleSplit_data(X, y):
    sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
    for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
        print("len(TRAIN):", len(train_index), "len(TEST):", len(test_index))
        print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

        train_data = [df.loc[ind] for ind in train_index]
        test_data = [df.loc[ind] for ind in test_index]
        save_datarows(train_data, datafile+".train")
        save_datarows(test_data, datafile+".test")
```

Comment: So, your main doubt is the line "train_data = [df.loc[ind] for ind in train_index]", right?

Comment: yes and the last two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Panda package,

```
 pd.DataFrame.loc
```

is kind of location-based indexer - This is an oversimplified version. I will post some resources that can help you understand it better.

```
train_data = [df.loc[ind] for ind in train_index]
```

Here you basically iterate over the list ind and store the respective values  train_data
similarly for the case of test_data

I assume that save_datarows is a custom function to store train_data into a file with extension .train

Hope this helps.

This is a really good reference for more clarification:

[Selection with .loc in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890713/selection-with-loc-in-python)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-loc/