# slicing with .loc in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was reading the book - "Python for Data Analysis" and doing code side-by-side on Jupiter notebook.
Here is my DataFrame named data :

```
                 one    three   four
       Ohio       0       2      3
       Colorado   4       6      7
       Utah       8       10    11
       New York   12      14    15
```

and I used : `data.loc[:"one"]`.
It gives a Keyerror 'one'. 
But when I use: `data.loc[:"Utah" , "one"]`. It doesn't give any error.
Can anyone tell me what's going one here. 
So the **problem is solved**.
 The error was I was missing a comma(,).
I have to do something like this :

```
data.loc[:,"one"]
```

but i was doing `data.loc[:"one"]` which gave error. But we don't have to include "," while we are dealing with more than one column or it will give error( kind of weird syntax ).
eg :  do this : `data.loc[:"Utah","one"]` 
not this : `data.loc[:,"Utah","one"]`

Comment: What are you trying to slice? There is no "one" in the index. If you want the columns: `data.loc[:, :"one"]`, or `data["one"]`

Comment: Yeah, that was too early for me to ask the question. The book later guided that for one column I have to use comma(,) after :

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selection with .loc in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890713/selection-with-loc-in-python)